# Configure a default directory path in Go with Cobra and Viper

Tags: go, go-cobra, viper-go

I want the user of my CLI app to enter a specific path where they want to save files.
I tried to use Cobra's --config flag but I don't know how to.

Example:

```sh
app --config path "~/Documents/"
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to sepcify a absolute path.

```sh
app --config path "$HOME/Documents/"
```